# How do I clear a field in json using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want the password fields to be set as blank when I run the script in my config.json it contains the following data

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": "user1",
    "password": "Password" 
  },
  "data2":{    
    "user": "user2",
    "password": "Password2"
  }
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: you can use JSON object and functions through jscript (with a few tricks).I hope I'll have to write you an example today. Another approach is to use powershell.

Comment: A lame approach could be done from batch (processing strings), but I'd recommend using other technology, that deals with *JSON*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try with this hybrid code Batch+Vbscript using a RegEx :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 52,3 & color 0A
Title Clear a field in json using batch file
Set "Tmpvbs=%temp%\Tmpvbs.vbs"
Set "InputFile=config.json"
Set "OutPutFile=result.txt"
Call :ReplaceData "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
echo(
Echo  All passwords fields in "%InputFile%" are cleared
TimeOut /T 3 /nobreak>nul & exit
::****************************************************
:ReplaceData <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Set myRegExp = New RegExp
echo myRegExp.Global = True
echo myRegExp.Pattern = "(""password"":)(\W.*)"
echo ResultString = myRegExp.Replace(Data, """password"": """""^)
echo WScript.echo ResultString
)>"%Tmpvbs%"
cscript //nologo "%Tmpvbs%" < "%~1" > "%~2"
Move /y "%~2" "%~1">nul
If Exist "%Tmpvbs%" Del "%Tmpvbs%"
exit /b
::****************************************************
```

So, as result, you can get your `config.json` like this one :

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": "user1",
    "password": ""
  },
  "data2":{    
    "user": "user2",
    "password": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working but I need to replace the input file. How do we do that ??